# Django - how to redirect the first logged in user to a loading page

Tags: django, redirect, receiver

Definition of ***The first logged in user***: the first one to authenticate, meaning no one else in that moment is logged in except him.

This django webapp needs to rely on a third parties rest api (Microsoft powerbi), which get paid per minute, but it also provide the possibility to turn on and off the server programmatically with a rest api call to azure.

The most obvious way to turn on and off the server, it seems to be to react at the first login and the last logout.

The issue here, is that the server needs about 30 seconds to start. And I need to redirect the user to a "loading" page, and when server is up, i would redirect him again to the home page.

currently, I detect the first login with a receiver, in my views.py I have:

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def sig_user_logged_in(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print("user logged in: %s at %s" % (user, request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    queryset = get_current_users()
    if queryset.count() == 0:
        headers_capacity = azure_auth_capacity()
        print("resuming capacity...")
        resume_pbi_capacity(headers_capacity)
        print("redirecting to loading page...")
        # Both following tries to redirect does not work
        #return '/loading/'
        #return render_to_response("loading.html")
```

Here I would redirect the user to a loading page as you see, since the server is taking 30 seconds to be ready, but the redirect does not happen at all. 
It seems to me that this function is not able to redirect because in the mean while an other function is running and "keeping busy the redirect system",

may be because of this parameter defined into settings.py that redirect right after login to the "home":

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Or may be this consequently called function defined into url.py:

```
path('', pbi_dashboard_list, name='home'),
```

Which execute the following view:

```
@login_required
def pbi_dashboard_list(request):
    # Some irrilevant code here, then redirect to an other page 
    return redirect('dashboard', dashboard_id)
```

It seems to be that the redirection system is busy here, and for this reason I'm not able to perform the redirect defined into sig_user_logged_in().

Anyone can point me out a good direction on this?

Edit:

```
def get_current_users():
    active_sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
    user_id_list = []
    for session in active_sessions:
        data = session.get_decoded()
        user_id_list.append(data.get('_auth_user_id', None))
    # Query all logged in users based on id list
    return User.objects.filter(id__in=user_id_list)
```

Comment: Is the function `resume_pbi_capacity()` actually waiting 30 secs for Azure to come back with a success message? Is so, then you need to move this to an asynchronous background thread so that it doesn't block the main app. A signal is synchronous, it's just a "detour" in the code flow, but it happens during the log in and blocks the return of the login view until it's done.

Comment: Second, you need to redirect your user in the view, not in a signal, as @Daniel mentions below. That shouldn't be difficult, you're probably making a call to your API somewhere in the view, just make the call with a relatively short timeout and if it times out, redirect your user to the "waiting" view (or render a waiting view), where javascript could reload the view after 30 secs.

Comment: I tried to move the redirect logic into the view function, but the issue here is that i'm not able to check if it is the first user to login, since in the view the user is already logged, in for this reason the get_current_users() will return 1, instead in the @receiver the first user is still not logged in, but the application received a login signal, this can provide me the information that's is the first.

Comment: No, I'm saying these should be different processes. The logic to check and start your Azure instance should be in the signal handler, that's fine. As long as `resume_pbi_capacity` returns immediately (does its job in the background). Your login view should just redirect normally to the dashboard. Then, the dashboard view (which is calling your Azure API) should time out and show the waiting message.

Comment: Ok I understand, I will try this : ) thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are many many issues here.

Firstly, in order to redirect you need to actually return a redirect, not just a URL or a rendered template. For example:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
...
return redirect('loading')
```

**However**, this is *only* something you can do from a view. You cannot redirect from a signal; that's just not something that even makes sense to do. The whole point of a signal is that it's for carrying out side effects that are unrelated to the main flow. You don't have access to the request or the response here.

So unfortunately your whole approach is wrong. (And that's not even to talk about how you identify "current logged in users"; you haven't shown your `get_current_users` logic but I highly doubt it works as you think it does.)

Comment: you are making me blush :`) , I 've updated the question adding the get_current_users function, I understand that my approach is wrong, I'm tring to figure out the right road to achieve that